# how to add two package in device_owner.xml?

Tags: android, device-owner

i want to create Kiosk Mode on my tablet and i have one application and one launcher ,and i want to task lock in both , if i put application and launcher in one package , may be force close cause , close both of them ,  so that i want to have two package in device_owner.xml , is that possible ?
or have any idea for my problem ?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
 <device-owner package="com.fajr.launcher" name="Fajr_Launcher"/>
 <device-owner package="com.fajr.sharifood" name="Fajr_ShariFood"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be only one device owner, but the device owner should be able to grant task locking permission to more than one package.  [DevicePolicyManager#setLockTaskPackages(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setLockTaskPackages%28android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String[]%29) takes an array of package names.  Even the device owner doesn't have that permission until it grants it to itself.  (Disclaimer: I haven't tried this with more than one package.)

Comment: i tried it for two package but it dont work . when im in first app , i cant open the second app !!! dose it mean that i must unpin first app and after it , open the second app ?

Comment: @hossein The first app should be able to launch an activity from the second app, as long as the activity allows itself to be launched into the first app's task.

Comment: thakns for your explain . when i pinned screen as admin , even though i added the the second app package , but i cant launch to the second app . the way that i found is : before you launch to second app , you must unpin first app , then launch to second app then in second app , at first pin the screen , and get the control of screen before user !